# projection of a matrix to the the space such that the diagonal elements are the greatest

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Suppose there is a symmetric matrix $A$ in $\mathcal{S}^n$. I would like to compute the nearest symmetric matrix $X \in \mathcal{S}^n$ such that $X_{ij} \le X_{ii}$, $i ,j \in \{1,...,n \}$. In other words, I am not sure how to solve the following problem:
\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{aligned}
&\min_{X \in \mathcal{S_g}} \| X-A \| \\
\mbox{where} \quad &\mathcal S_g=\{X\in \mathcal S^n\colon X_{ij} \le X_{ii}, i ,j \in \{1,...,n \}\}
\end{aligned}
\end{eqnarray}
The norm is Frobenius norm. 
At the moment, I can only do the partial projection, i.e., I can project it separately for each $i$. Any suggestions?